# ExtJs 4 field.Text pre-render function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an input box (textfield component, Ext.form.field.Text) on my form.
I place the data into this componen using a function

```
window.getForm().loadRecord(myRecords)
```

But data represented into `myRecords` array hasen't been formatted. I need a "pre-renderring" function in a MyTextField component (which extending a standard field.Text component). How I can implement this function?

Comment: Can you create sencha fiddle for issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pre-rendering function, my guess is that you also need a pre-save function to convert values in the field back into values in your record.

For these two tasks, you can override the [`rawToValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-rawToValue) and [`valueToRaw`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-valueToRaw) functions on your field.